# Find Different Combinations of Events and Calculate Time Between in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have data from a bunch of camera traps and for each camera I need to calculate the time (in minutes) between detections of two species (let's say coyote and fox) but I need several different versions of this. For each camera I need to pull out every instance of the 4 below criteria and then get the average of each for each camera, or print NA since these don't exist at every camera.

The 4 criteria are:

1. The time from a fox detection to the next coyote detection (T1).
2. The time from a coyote detection to the next fox detection. If there is more than 1 coyote detection between foxes I need the time from the first coyote to the fox (T2).
3. The time from a fox detection to the next fox detection without a coyote detection in between (T3).
4. The time from a fox detection to the next fox detection with a coyote detection in between (T4).

I think this could be accomplished with a for loop but I am terrible at those so would greatly appreciate any help!

Here is an example of my data:

```
df <- data.frame(row=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
camera=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C"),
species=c("fox", "coyote" ,"coyote","fox", "fox", "coyote" , "fox", "fox", "coyote" , "fox","coyote", "coyote" ),
date and time=c("1/15/2019 1:15:00","1/15/2019 13:45","1/19/2019 2:29","1/26/2019 0:08","1/26/2019 4:07","1/31/2019 17:20","2/3/2019 1:04","2/4/2019 6:31","2/4/2019 20:23","2/7/2019 18:52", "2/10/2019 4:13", "1/9/2019 19:20"))
df
```

| Row | Camera | Species | Date and Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | fox | 1/15/2019 1:15:00 |
| 2 | A | coyote | 1/15/2019 13:45:00 |
| 3 | A | coyote | 1/19/2019 2:29:00 |
| 4 | A | fox | 1/26/2019 0:08:00 |
| 5 | A | fox | 1/26/2019 4:07:00 |
| 6 | A | coyote | 1/31/2019 17:20:00 |
| 7 | B | fox | 2/3/2019 1:04:00 |
| 8 | B | fox | 2/4/2019 6:31:00 |
| 9 | B | coyote | 2/4/2019 20:23:00 |
| 10 | B | fox | 2/7/2019 18:52:00 |
| 11 | C | coyote | 2/10/2019 4:13:00 |
| 12 | C | coyote | 1/9/2019 19:20:00 |

So I need the time between rows 1 and 2, 5 and 6 (T1), 2 and 4 (T2), 1 and 4 (T4), 4 and 5 (T5) etc. I would like to end up with a table like this:

| Camera | Criteria | Average Time (Minutes) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | T1 | 771.5 |
| A | T2 | 623 |
| A | T3 | 239 |
| A | T4 | 1373 |
| B | T1 | 832 |
| B | T2 | 1349 |
| B | T3 | 327 |
| B | T4 | 741 |
| C | T1 | NA |
| C | T2 | NA |
| C | T3 | NA |
| C | T4 | NA |

Comment: how did you get 891.5mins for camera A and criteria T1? Which rows of fox and coyote did you used?

Comment: Can you provide your data in a reproducible format which is easier to copy preferably with `dput` ?  Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: For camera A criteria T1 I took the average of the time difference between row 1 and 2 and 5 and 6 . I realized I made an error though, it should be 771.5. I fixed this in the example. I also added reproducible data. I just figured out how to use dput so I will use that in the future.